# How to find documents that contain property inside array in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

After reading all online resources that I could think of still unable to think of solution to this one. Basically, I have documents with following data in mongo:

```
// 1
{
  a: {
    b: {
      languages: {
        en: {
          text: "en",
          type: "secret"
        },
        de: {
          text: "de"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//2
{
  a: {
    b: {
      languages: {
        fr: {
          text: "fr"
        },
        de: {
          text: "de",
          type: "public"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

this returns me whatever the first document is, it doesn't matter when I change the `secret` to whatever:

```
db.products.findOne({"a.b.languages": {$exists: {$elemMatch: {"type": {$eq: "secret"}}}}}, {"key": 1, "a.b.languages": 1})
```

What I'm after is all the documents that contain languages of certain type - this field is also optional. How could I construct such a query?

Also if this problem is standard please provide me info so that I could update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing here is that there's no array in your documents - you just have nested objects with unknown keys. To query that kind of structure you need to convert those nested documents into an array using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) operator.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            languages: { $objectToArray: "$a.b.languages" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "languages.v.type": "secret" }
    },
    {
        $project: { languages: 0 }
    }
])
```

above code will convert `a.b.languages` path into an array of keys and values (object with `k` and `v` fields) so you can query directly referencing `languages.v.type` then. `$addFields` and `$project` are used to generate and then remove temporary field that can be queried.

Comment: you nailed it, thanks that was exactly what I was looking for!